# Template suggestion for 'content' in custom page

Tags: hooks, theming

I need the equivalent for hook_preprocess_node for custom pages, which aren't nodes.

The particular page I need to theme is provided by the entity registration module 'node/10/register'. I can add theme suggestions for the page using hook_preprocess_page - but how to I add a theme suggestion for the actual content, so I don't have to rewrite the page.tpl.php?

Alternatively if there is an existing pattern to name the file then that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the file

```
entity.tpl.php
```

from the theme directory of the module : entity.

Paste it into your theme's template directory, and rename it to

```
registration.tpl.php
```

Other theme suggestions are:

```
registration__TYPE
registration__TYPE__VIEWMODE
registration__ID
```

If you want to have access to the preprocess function then add this function to your theme's template.php file :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_entity(&$vars) {
  //dpm($vars);
}
```

Comment: It's not a template for the entity itself, it's the page node/10/register - which is the registration form. The registration entity itself is the submitted results of this form.

Comment: In that case you want to theme a form, and you will have to create your own theme function to do that. You need to implement hook_theme and use the form ID as the array key. Once you have a theme function then you can create a preprocess to go with it.